# newspaper(python) get all cnn news list

Tags: python, html, python-newspaper

in this url (https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555)

my Purpose is getting all news list

In url`s html code(contain news`s url )

```
 <div class="cnn-search__result-thumbnail">         
 <a href="https://www.cnn.com/2018/03/27/asia/north-korea-kim-jong-un-china- visit/index.html">
   <img src="./Search CNN - Videos, Pictures, and News - 
      CNN.com_files/180328104116china-xi-kim-story-body.jpg">
   </a>
```

can not get url`s news list

https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5550&page=556 `s link

https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5560&page=557 `s link is same

my source code

```
def freeze_support():
 '''
 Check whether this is a fake forked process in a frozen executable.
 If so then run code specified by commandline and exit.
 '''
 if sys.platform == 'win32' and getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
     from multiprocessing.forking import freeze_support
     freeze_support()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  freeze_support()
  for x in range(1, 6000):
    url = "https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=" + str(x * 10) + "&page=" + str(x + 1)
    cnn_paper = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)  # ~15 seconds
    print(len(cnn_paper.articles))
    list = []
    for article in cnn_paper.articles:
        if article.url not in url_list:
            list.append(article.url)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5550&page=556 https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555 result is same but two link contain different news list

Comment: can you please make it clear what are you trying to say here?

Comment: also, both the links are not actually same, they have different parameters for page...which is a pagination functionality

Comment: both link are not same but each link get 10 news i want to get each link`s news url  In this code get same link not each news url